# Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function firebase

Tags: android, firebase

> this error Multiple dex files define Landroid/arch/core/util/Function;
>   if i add   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'

[this is image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ck4Y7.png)

[this is image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFkVm.png)

[this is image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9K0J.png)

Answer (score 2):

To solve this, please change in your build.gradle file (Project) the following lines of code:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'
```